# set same style for input and button, but they look different

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
input{
  height:30px;
  width:77px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
button{
  height:30px;
  width:77px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
select{
height:30px;
  width:77px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input value="value" name="test" type="text"/>
<select></select>
<button>test</button>
```

I have input, select and button these three element all have the same style, but they look different, could anybody please tell me why?

Comment: you want text input look like a button? Try using input type=submit. Or let us know what you expect to see with this styles

Comment: Each browser has its own default styles for each element. Various brands have slightly different default styles as well. You can use CSS Reset to align all the styles across different browsers.

Comment: Use a CSS Reset. Plenty of them out on the internet

Answer (score 1):

The browser applies default styling for each element. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/abc52743caa0a019d359ec4ba2ce965b) some of those. There are libraries like [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) that reset some of these styles and creates consistency between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser default styling,

you can fix it by adding :

```
input{box-sizing:border-box}
```

the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input resize value="value" name="test" type="text"/>
<select></select>
<button>test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

css :

```
  input,button,select{
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  width:77px;
  margin:10px;
  margin:10;
    
}
input{box-sizing:border-box}
```

I combined your css since you are going to apply the same option for all the elements.

[demo](https://codepen.io/shahemm/pen/VwMbPbm?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

So, the browser has a default styles for each element, and you need to overwrite these style, the best solution i found is to combining the three selectors and adding `background-color: white` and `border: 1px solid black` for the button and `box-sizing: border-box` to fix the height.

```css
   
input, select, button{
  height:30px;
  width:77px;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<input value="value" name="test" type="text"/>
<select></select>
<button>test</button>
```